# Running parallel in background

Tags: c#, wpf, background, parallel-processing

Main question is: How to run the code within  TestingButton_Click on several threads in background (similar to BackgroundWorker) so I will be able to:
1. Get all the raw data to the methods
2. Cancel test for all threads simultaneously
3. Report progress
4. Retrieve all the result tables to main thread.

The following code is within TestingButton_Click

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

            //Testing for each pair
            foreach (InterfaceWithClassName aCompound in Group1)
            {
                foreach (InterfaceWithClassName bCompound in Group2)
                {
                    InstancePair pair = new InstancePair();
                    //some code

                    if (testModeParallel)
                    {
                        Thread thr = new Thread(TestPairParallel);
                        thr.Start(pair);
                        threads.Add(thr);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Thread thr = new Thread(TestPairSerial);
                        thr.Start(pair);
                        threads.Add(thr);
                    }
                }
            }              

            while (true)
            {
                int i = 0;

                foreach (Thread thread in threads)
                {
                    if (thread.IsAlive)
                        break;

                    i++;
                }

                if (i == threads.Count)
                    break;

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            pairsResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = tab.DefaultView
```

User is able to choose what compounds to test so every time I have different number of pairs to test.
I made to different methods TestPairSerial() and TestPairParallel() just in case.

TestPairSerial() structure is

```
        do
        {
            do
            {

            } while (isSetbCompaundParams);

        } while (isSetaCompaundParams);

        //filling up results into tables (main window variables) later to be connected to DataGrids
```

TestPairParallel() is implemented with InfinitePartitioner and using similar structure only with Parallel.ForEach(new InfinitePartitioner(),...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  Your first sentence makes no sense.  Come up with a single question.  I suggest you lose the background information since it has nothing to do with your current problem.

Comment: Take a look at the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) class

Comment: Please choose a single question to ask, and post only the information relevant to that question.

Comment: Edited, but there are 4 questions because they are related.

Comment: @Vitaly - Lets deal with a single question.  There is no reason this cannot be 4 seperate question, lets address one at a time, much easier on us and this will allow you to understand our answers ( instead of simply providing you working code that you don't understand ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to run the code within TestingButton_Click on several threads in
>   background.

I would use a **Task** as they were design to do exactly what you want.

The only other question I will answer until you get closer to the actual solution is the following:

> Report progress

There are lots of ways to report the progress on a given thread, you would have to subscribe to an event, and write code to report the progress of the thread.  In order to update a control on the form, this would require you Invoke the change, this is not a trivial feature.

Comment: Thank you. I better study TPL first before I ask any further questions. Seems like everyone of you are pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET 4.0 Tasks instead of creating new Threads yourself. Tasks give you finer granularity of control, make it easy to pass data into the background operation, and provide excellent support for waiting for results across multiple concurrent tasks and for cancellation of everything in one fell swoop if needed.  Highly recommended.

Comment: Do they provide progress report? (Like BackgroundWorker).

Comment: @Vitaly - They can...If you code it.  There is nothing special about BackgroundWorker it just has events which you can subscribe to.  You still have to write the code, to update some control, using an Invoke.